# properties of equality: real vs. complex numbers

Tags: terminology, axioms

When researching the reflexive, symmetric, transitive, addition, subtraction, multiplication, division, and substitution properties of equality, the sources I found said they were true "for all real numbers".  Are any or all of them not true for complex numbers?  i.e., is the "for all real numbers" a necessary caveat, or should it say "for all numbers"?  Also, I know the reflexive property applies to mathematical objects as well (any mathematical object is congruent to itself).  Do the other properties of equality apply to all mathematical objects as well?

Comment: all of them are true for complex numbers as well

Comment: *the sources I found* -- could you link to these?

Comment: Yes, reflexive, symmetric, transitive and substitution properties hold for every kind of [equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms).